# How to combine or join unique values from different columns in DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[image: This is my Dataset and I want to combine Symptom_1, Symptom_2, Symptom_3]

This is my Dataset and I want to combine Symptom_1, Symptom_2, Symptom_3.
The code that I used to combine them is

```py
df['Symptom'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Symptom_1 + row.Symptom_2 + row.Symptom_3, axis=1,)
df.head()
```

But the problem in this is that the Symptom column does not contain a seperator ',' between values

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can try

```py
df['Symptom'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join([row.Symptom_1, row.Symptom_2, row.Symptom_3]), axis=1,)
# or
df['Symptom'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.filter(like='Symptom')), axis=1,)
# or
df['Symptom'] = df.filter(like='Symptom').apply(','.join, axis=1)
```

If you only want to keep the unique value, you can try

```py
df['Symptom'] = df.apply(lambda row: ','.join(row.filter(like='Symptom').drop_duplicates()), axis=1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Symptom'] = df['Symptom_1'].str.cat(df[['Symptom_2', 'Symptom_3']], sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

just add separator inbetween

```
df['Symptom'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Symptom_1 + ',' + row.Symptom_2 +  ',' + row.Symptom_3, axis=1,)
```